# Youtube API crash when no Video ID is present in Android Studio

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am using **Youtube API** in my application and it works okay, but the problem is that when I do not put any youtube **video id** in it, it gets **crashed** and my **application gets closed**, I do not know why this problem is occuring. I am also using **Firebase** and from Firebase Database I am geting the Video ID. the other problem I am getting with Youtube API is that if there is no video ID present the video player should **hide** itself but it is always visable, please help.

> I am using Android studio

**Youtube API xml file:**

```
 <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/youtuber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />
```

**Youtube FirebaseAdapter class:**

```
 public void setYoutube(final String youtube){
            final YouTubePlayerView youPlay = (YouTubePlayerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.youtuber);
            youPlay.initialize("KEY",
                    new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                            YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

                            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(youtube);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                            YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                        }
                    });
        }
```

Comment: I think that is the behavior of the Youtube API, when you do not put any youtube video id, your code will not play any video that is why it get crashed.

Answer (score 1):

In order to play videos, you need ID parameter to identify the video as stated in the Official Google Documentation.

Check this reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos

Answer (score 0):

To keep it open, set up a short blank video on youtube.
Then have an "if (){...}" statement to put that video ID into the player if no other ID is available.

This can be your "ERROR" or "Holding" page.